# Node Express 404 error when trying to load image uploaded by multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

Im trying to upload images with multer. Everything has worked before on localhost fine. Images get uploaded and i can view them from the url link the code provides. However once i have uploaded it on a server im starting to get this error : "Cannot GET /marketplace-api/rest-api/image/1650484814178.jpg".

I have not provided link to server/domains to the question in case people say thats the problem.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const db = require('./db');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = 5000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true , limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(cors());



app.use("/image", express.static("image")); 
let imageName = ""; 
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: path.join("./image"), 
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    imageName = Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, imageName);
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 3000000 },
}).single("myImage");
app.post("/marketplace-api/rest-api/upload-image", (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      return res.status(201)
      .json({ url: "http://link to domains/marketplace-api/rest-api/image/" + imageName }); 
    }
  });
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server run in port", port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, few things, 1. you dont have any get functions, which means you cant post to this location, i suggest doing this:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

and create a file called index.html, go on your site (localhost), and it should work, after that add a form in the html file, it should look something like this

```html
<form action = "/marketplace-api/rest-api/upload-image" method = "POST">
    <input type = "file" name="image">
    <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

this will add a basic form where you can upload your photo.
there are a few more stuff to add / change, i will fix everything and make it a repo then send it here

Comment: not working at all still getting cannot GET/ .    There for sure shouldnt be need for a index.html file if im uploading this image through postman right? The question was meant why i cannot open the images I'm uploading but thank you anyway